# Pyspark in docker container postgresql dababase connection

Tags: postgresql, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to connect to a postgres database on the localhost:5432 of my computer using pyspark inside a docker container. For this I use VS code. VS code automatically builds and runs the container. This is the code I have:

```
password = ...
user = ...
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres'

    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars","/opt/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
        .appName("PySpark_Postgres_test").getOrCreate()
        
    
df = connector.read.format("jbdc") \
.option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", 'chicago_crime') \
        .option("user", user) \
            .option("password", password) \
                .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
                    .load()
```

I keep getting the same error:

> "An error occurred while calling o358.load.\n:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \nFailed to find data source: jbdc. ...

Maybe the url is not correct?

```
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres'
```

The database is on port **5432** and has the name **postgres**. The database is on my localhost but since I am working in a docker container I assumed the correct way would be to enter the ip adress of your laptops localhost **127.0.0.1**. If you type **localhost** it would refer to the localhost of your docker container. Or should I use the **IPv4 Address** (Wireless Lan .. or wsl).

Anyone knows what's wrong?

ps, one of the commands in my dockerfile is the following:

```
RUN wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.5.jar -P /opt/spark/jars
```

Comment: Can you show the Docker compose setup you are using to launch the database?

Comment: I am not using a Docker compose. Should I? To map the ports or something.

Comment: If you're not using docker-conpose, then can you share the docker run command you're using? Also, can you try once with host.docker.internal:5432, instead of 127.0.0.1:5432 and let us know the results

Comment: I forgot to say that I do the development in vs code. VS code builds and runs the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "/opt/spark/jars/postgresql-42.2.5.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
    
df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/postgres") \
    .option("dbtable", "chicago_crime") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "postgres") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()
```